# Following: How to use FTS in SQLite with Monotouch for iOS

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin.ios, full-text-search, fts3

I'm currently following this small tutorial about MonoTouch, SQLite and FTS3: 
[How to use FTS in SQLite with Monotouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5372409/how-to-use-fts-in-sqlite-with-monotouch-for-ios)

I've sucessfully done step 1 and 2. Unfurtunatelly I'm facing a problem on step 3, because when i try to compile the iPhone monotocuh project I got this error:

> Error 1: mtouch failed with the following message: Process exited with
>   code 1, command:
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2
>   -arch i386 -gdwarf-2 -fobjc-legacy-dispatch -fobjc-abi-version=2
>   -miphoneos-version-min=4.2   -isysroot
>   /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator4.2.sdk
>   /var/folders/lu/luWKJVufEMO0MYd3+T3MJ++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp4f24ee90.tmp/main.x86.o
>   -o
>   /var/folders/lu/luWKJVufEMO0MYd3+T3MJ++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp4f24ee90.tmp/Iusuite
>   -framework CFNetwork -framework AssetsLibrary -framework CoreTelephony
>   -framework EventKit -framework Foundation -framework CoreMotion
>   -framework GameKit -framework MapKit -framework MediaPlayer -framework
>   MessageUI -framework OpenGLES -framework StoreKit -framework UIKit
>   -framework AddressBookUI -framework iAd -framework SystemConfiguration
>   -framework AddressBook -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation
>   -framework QuartzCore -framework CoreFoundation -framework
>   CoreGraphics -framework CoreLocation -framework ImageIO -framework
>   Security -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreVideo -framework
>   ExternalAccessory -framework EventKitUI -framework QuickLook
>   -framework AudioToolbox -lz -u _mono_pmip -u _CreateZStream -u
>   _CloseZStream -u _Flush -u _ReadZStream -u _WriteZStream -liconv
>   -lmono-2.0 -lmonotouch
>   -L/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphonesimulator.sdk/usr/lib -u
>   _catch_exception_raise
>   -L/Users/user/Develop/MonoDevelop/.../
>   -lSQLite3_iOS -force_load
>   /Users/user/Develop/MonoDevelop/.../Libraries/libSQLite3_iOS.a
>
> ld: library not found for -lSQLite3_iOS collect2: ld returned 1 exit
>   status  (1) (Iusuite.Application)

This is what i use as additional command for monotouch

**-gcc_flags "-L${ProjectDir} -lSQLite3_iOS -force_load ${ProjectDir}/Libraries/libSQLite3_iOS.a"**

Any hint or idea?

thanks to all
Francesco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're building your own sqlite library and you need to make sure you're using this library from your MonoTouch project.

The extra arguments you're giving **mtouch** ask **gcc** to link your new library. The given path is:

/Users/francesco/Develop/MonoDevelop/AdMaiora/Applications/src/AdMaiora.Iusuite/Iusuite.App.Apple/Iusuite.Application/Libraries/libSQLite3_iOS.a

Does that file exists on your system ? If not then look for the file and either update your extra arguments or move the library to the location you provided.

Note: it's uncommon to provide **-L${ProjectDir}** and then specify **-force_load ${ProjectDir}/Libraries/libSQLite3_iOS.a** (note the extra **/Libraries/** in the path).

Comment: Hi Poupou, yes the libSQLite3_iIOS.a file exists. I have manually copied it into ${ProjectDir}/Libraries after having successfully built it with XCode.

I have removed the -L${ProjectDir} parameter and now the project compile sucessfully. Next step, try to invoke the methods.